# Can chef synchronize a bootstrap process across multiple machines

Tags: chef-infra

Our deployment process deploys to multiple machines, where the steps must be synchronized across the machines. (i.e. Step 2 on machine 2 depends on Step 1 running on machine 1)

Does chef support bootstrapping multiple machines as a single synchronized process?

This must apply to a local Chef server (not hosted).

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chef is a configuration management tool. it's not really designed to do multi-node orchestration. 
If you want to chef boostrap several cooperating nodes then I'd suggest looking at [Spiceweasel](https://github.com/mattray/spiceweasel), it might have what you need.

I've noticed others using chef recipes to model different deployment life-cycle actions, but such systems never seem to play nice with chef server... They tend to leverage chef-solo, but then need a 3rd party tool to trigger chef...

The question I've been asking for some time is whether chef is suitable for application deployment. Clearly it can be used for this purpose as evidenced by cookbooks like  [artifact](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/artifact) and [application](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/application). The thing is I can't help shaking that feeling that perhaps we're stretching the boundaries of chef. There are lots open source orchestration tools out there, my personal favourite is [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/). The opscode folks are also busy developing a new tool called [pushy](http://docs.opscode.com/pushy.html) so I continue to watch this space with interest.

Answer (score 2):

How about cluster_chef, which is now called IronFan?

https://github.com/infochimps-labs/ironfan

Comment: I've also looked at this with interest. I especially like the silverware cookbook, used for discovery. My concerns in this space is the added complexity and lack of standardization, for example the ironfan cookbooks do not appear to be part of the community website. Since I authored this answer I've been looking at alternative application deployment strategies that use Docker. I high recommend looking at Deis: http://deis.io/ It's a killer application for Chef and don't understand why opscode doesn't promote it.